Two sisters live alone in a house after the rest of their family died
I read this in the mid-90s while in Ashland, KY, from a shelf of books in our house that was largely occupied by books my parents had owned before us kids, so there's a good chance that the book is older than the 1980s. The two main characters are two sisters, living alone in the family home. The younger was fairly young, prepubescent, and I think the older was about 6-8 years older, just enough to be considered an adult. The rest of the family (parents, and at least some siblings as I remember it) died in a mysterious accident years before, and it's common knowledge in the town that the older girl did it, although no one agrees why. I remember that the younger girl was fairly wild, always running around barefoot in the surrounding woods, and was a very happy, if passionate, young girl, compared to the older sister who was much colder, and sometimes seemingly cruel to the younger sister.
I don't remember the exact time period that the book was set in, but my impression was that it was probably somewhere in the mid 20th century or before because it was not terribly scandalous that the younger sister had not attended school since the death of her family. Most of the book was about the family drama between the two, and gradually learning more about what happened that fateful day with the family.

 It turns out that it was the younger sister who had killed the rest of the family, adding something poisonous to the meal in a fit of pique. I think that she hadn't meant to kill them, just make them sick. She survived because she knew not to eat what she poisoned and I think her sister wasn't feeling well and had skipped dinner, something used as evidence by the townspeople that she was the poisoner.

I vaguely remember the cover as being fairly simple, mostly one color, maybe green, and showing one of the young women standing forlornly, looking more or less at the viewer. Unfortunately, my memory there is very vague, and I don't know if it's mixed up with other books I've read over the years.

This sounds a little bit like Shirley Jackson's novel We Have Always Lived in the Castle, although not all the details agree. There's a good summary of it in Wikipedia. From this summary:

Mary Katherine "Merricat" Blackwood lives with her older sister Constance and their ailing Uncle Julian in a large house on extensive grounds, in isolation from the nearby village.
...
Six years prior, Constance and Merricat's parents John and Ellen, their aunt Dorothy, and their younger brother Thomas died after being poisoned with arsenic, which was mixed into the family's sugar bowl and sprinkled onto blackberries at dinner.

One difference from your description is that in We Have Always Lived in the Castle,

 The poisoning was deliberate (at least in my distant memory of the book, and according to Wikipedia).


I think I misremembered the one character's gleeful description of poisonous mushrooms with their choice of poisons.
